# Aptana Studio or Zend Studio

Tags: aptana, zend-studio

I want create a full website (designing and programming). And I like created it by me.
for an editor, Aptana studio is better for me or Zend Studio?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Aptana.  Studio 3 is now out and works nicely.  More vim-ish.

Answer (score 3):

On my computer I installed Aptana Studio 3 and Zend Studio 9 trial.
- It seems (i am sure) both studios have the same background (eclipse).
- There is same user interface, look and menu structure.
- Installation directory structure is very similar. (same)
- From developer point of view Zend has much more posibilities. (zend server, etc.)
- There are few features in Aptana not find in Zend 
  (block selection mode, show whitespace char, Themes, etc.)

My suggestion - download and try both. When You learn one studio, Your investment will valid also for other. (unfortunately Zend is not free)

2012.01.24
Bruster

Answer (score 2):

At least, Aptana is free, ZendStudio 8 has been made on Eclipse foundation, I'm not sure whether Aptana is too, but I suppose it is made on Eclipse also.

Comment: Yes it is, Aptana has been made on Eclipse foundations too. It's similar (of course not the same) with ZS